# Console.log shows array but can't be returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, co

I'm new to working with promises (I'm using 'co' in node) so I'm not entirely sure what's failing with this code:

```
function* excelToJSON(excelFileNames) {
  var jsonData = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < excelFileNames.length; index++) {
    parseXlsx(excelFilesNames[index], function (err, data) {

      jsonData.push(data);
      console.log(jsonData); //***Shows data correctly
    });
  }

  console.log(jsonData); //***Empty array
  return yield jsonData;
}
```

It reads the file, converts it and, at least within the loop, it shows everything correctly, but once we get out of the loop the data seems to disappear. I've also tried to return one of the values from within the loop but that doesn't work either.

EDIT:
parseXlsx is from the 'excel' module here: https://github.com/trevordixon/excel.js
I'm not entirely sure if it's async or sync, to be honest. This seems to be its code, and I know 'extractFiles' returns a promise but since it then goes through 'parseXlsx' I'm not sure what happens afterwards:

```
function parseXlsx(path, sheet, cb) {
  if (typeof cb === 'undefined') {
    cb = sheet;
    sheet = '1';
  }
  extractFiles(path, sheet).then(function(files) {
    cb(null, extractData(files));
  },
  function(err) {
    cb(err);
  });
};
```

EDIT2:
What I used to solve it is a combination of several answers, thanks to all of you.

```js
function* excelToJSON(excelFileNames) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var jsonData = [];

    if (excelFilesNames === null || excelFilesNames.length === 0) {
      reject();
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < excelFilesNames.length; index++) {
      parseXlsx(excelFilesNames[index], function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        jsonData.push(data);

        if (jsonData.length === excelFilesNames.length) {
          resolve(jsonData);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is `parseXlsx` an async function ?

Comment: Nice, but what is the purpose of making a generator function here? Does this behave as an async function if a generator returns a promise?

Comment: It seems to be so. Check 'co':
https://www.npmjs.com/package/co

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's happening here is that your code just runs through that for block, invoking `parseXlsx` a few times, but never actually waits for it to finish.

So this is why your empty array log comes first, and then there come the logs with the 'correct data'. Look up javascript event loop to get a better understanding of how asynchronous functions work.

What you essentially need is either a promise that you resolve when you're done, or get a callback function that you'll call when you're done.

And you'll know when you're done when your `jsonData.push(data);` has been called as many times as long as your `excelFileNames` array is.

For example:

```
function excelToJSON(excelFileNames) {
  var deferred = Promise.defer();
  var jsonData = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < excelFileNames.length; index++) {
    parseXlsx(excelFilesNames[index], function (err, data) {

      jsonData.push(data);
      console.log(jsonData); //***Shows data correctly
      if (jsonData.length === excelFileNames.length) {
        deferred.resolve(jsonData);
      }
    });
  }

  return deferred.promise;
}

// And use it as a promise:

var exelToJsonPromise = excelToJSON(["apples.xlsx", "pears.xlsx]);

exelToJsonPromise.then(function(jsonData){ 
  console.log(jsonData); // Now this will have everything in it.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use just a counter & When to return, try something like this.

```
function* excelToJSON(excelFileNames) {
var jsonData = [];
var count=0;
  for (let index = 0; index < excelFileNames.length; index++) {
    parseXlsx(excelFilesNames[index], function (err, data) {

      jsonData.push(data);
      console.log(jsonData); //***Shows data correctly
          if(count==excelFileNames.length){
                console.log(jsonData); 
                return yield jsonData;
           }
        count++
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:**

parseXlsx is an **Asynchronous** call, so you won't get data back immediately.

---

**How to fix:**

do things in callback.

```
function* excelToJSON(excelFileNames, callback) {
  var jsonData = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < excelFileNames.length; index++) {
    parseXlsx(excelFilesNames[index], function (err, data) {

      jsonData.push(data);
      console.log(jsonData); //***Shows data correctly

      callback(jsonData);    // do what you want with the jsonData here.
    });
  }

  // console.log(jsonData); //***Empty array
  // return yield jsonData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a asynchronous framework. What is happening in your case is that the console.log(jsonData) outside the parseXlsx is getting called before the one inside. You can try the async waterfall method like this.

```
var pushData = function (err, data) {
    jsonData.push(data);
    console.log(jsonData);
};

function* excelToJSON(excelFileNames) {
    var jsonData = [];
    async.waterfall([
        function(){
            for (let index = 0; index < excelFileNames.length; index++) {
                parseXlsx(excelFilesNames[index], pushData);
            }
        }
    ], function() {
           console.log(jsonData);
           return yield jsonData;
    });
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall).

PS. It is also not a good practice to define a function inside of a loop.